# Solve $x^5 + x - 1 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, polynomials, roots

Solve $x^5 +x - 1 = 0$

I am simply curious to see how the solution would go, since it is a quintic; it cannot be done by regular methods.

I'm just curious to see what people would come up with, and I can not solve the equation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can factor it:
$$x^5+x-1=(x^2-x+1)\cdot (x^3+x^2-1)=0$$

Then solving these separately gives $$x=e^{\pm \frac{\pi i}{3}}$$ and some horrible solutions for the cubic.

Comment: Those solutions aren't horrible, for example the real solution simply is $$\frac13\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac12\cdot\left(25-3\sqrt{69}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\frac12\cdot\left(25+3\sqrt{69}\right)}-1\right)$$ If you want horrible solutions, look at the solutions for $x^5-x+1=0$

Comment: @KristofferRyhl, degrees of insanity.

Comment: Is there some way that you were able to see at a glance that it could be factored into a product of a cubic and quadratic?  Or did you just happen to know from having seen it before?

Comment: Actually, the reciprocal of $x$ is the [_Plastic Constant_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number), an interesting number that is the cubic analogue to the _golden ratio_. See also [A Tale of Four Constants](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0012) which also shows its nice q-continued fraction.

Comment: @Alex, how did you find the factors. or the one factor?